# Communication between Python and C TCP socket

Tags: python, c, dll, tcp, subprocess

I have a C executable which opens a TCP socket and communicates with a device.

I want my Python script to send messages to that C executable and in turn, the C program sends that message over the socket to the device.

I basically want to keep the socket alive from within C and use Python to send the messages.

I'm not entirely sure how to do so, maybe I need to make a DLL and maintain the connection from there, or from the executable itself, I don't know.

The C program is an entire project with many headers but the TCP connection is pretty straightforward so I don't think posting the code will be beneficial.

I'm kind of lost trying to accomplish this, I've been searching the internet for several days looking for a solution and found nothing useful.

Comment: If I understand what your ask, you want the C program act as a proxy between the python program and the device. That is easy since you already wrote half of the solution. Add a listening socket in your C program to accept TCP connection from you python program. And in the python program, use socket.send to send data to the C program. The C program has to run continuously.

Comment: You start the program. You connect to it using Python. You send messages and read responses. Since you didn't add any Python or C code, you shouldn't tag your question with those tags. If you have any specific question, do ask. But this is not a useful way of asking for help. Look into some C server socket programming and Python network client programming. Learn by doing, not by reading.